# Como puedo mandar un correo electronico usando un archivo xml?

Tags: c#, xml, email

Tengo un programa escrito en C# el cual tiene que mandar un correo electronico. Lo que busco hacer es que el contenido del correo venga desde un archivo xml.

Aqui es como tengo el codigo del envio de correos:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("FromTest@test.org", "ToTest@test.org");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 25;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Host = "localhost"; 
mail.Subject = "Testing email";
mail.Body = "This is a test email";
client.Send(mail);
```

Como podria hacer eso? hay alguna mejor manera de manejar el contenido del correo que no sea modificar el string cada vez que se necesite hacer cambios?

Saludos,

Comment: Lo que harias seria generar una string donde contengas el valor de cada parte del email, esta string la cargarias desde tu xml y procederias a asignarla a cada parte del correo.

Comment: @JesusRodríguez, eso estuve leyendo pero no encontre como implementarlo

Comment: Aqui hay multiples metodos para leer un xml: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752796/how-to-read-xml-in-net y http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119806/reading-data-from-xml?noredirect=1&lq=1 , el resto solo es almacenar los valores del metodo que elijas en variables y asignarlos a mail.Subject y mail.body

Comment: @Aarancibia Al decir: "contenido", ¿Estás diciendo que quieres solo el `mensaje` del correo, o es toda la información relacionada al correo: Asunto, destinatario, mensaje, etc.?. Si es solo el mensaje, debes intentar leer solo la estructura del XML. Ahora si quieres algo definido, puedes deserializar tu XML a una clase de `C#`, así podrías tener definido toda la información en un objeto. [XML DeSerialization in C#](http://www.csharptutorial.in/10/csharp-net-xml-deserialization-in-csharp)

Answer (score 1):

Para atajar el problema que tienes lo que necesitas hacer son los siguientes pasos.

Para guardar los datos en un xml:

1. Crear una clase que contenga los datos
2. Serializar la clase
3. Guardar lo serializado en un archivo

Para recuperar los datos:

1. Leer y deserializar el archivo
2. Usar los datos

Por ejemplo para guardar los datos de tu email puedes usar esta clase:

```
public class EmailData
{
    public string MailTo { get; set; }
    public string MailFrom { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public SmtpDeliveryMethod SmtpDeliveryMethod { get; set; }
    public bool UseDefaultCredentials { get; set; }
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Para Serializar y deserializar objetos puedes usar estas extensiones que he creado:

```
 public static class SerializerExtensions
 {
    public static void SerializarYGuardar(this object value, string ruta)
    {
        try
        {
            var xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(value.GetType());
            var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
            {
                xmlserializer.Serialize(writer, value);
                StreamWriter strWr = File.CreateText(ruta);
                strWr.Write(stringWriter);
                strWr.Close();
                strWr.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Se ha producido un error", ex);
        }
    }


    public static T DesSerialize<T>(string rutafichero)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(rutafichero))
            {
                var xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                object obj = xmlserializer.Deserialize(streamRead);

                if (obj is T)
                    return (T)obj;
                else
                    throw new Exception("El objeto deserializado no es del tipo indicado");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Ha ocurrido un error:", ex);
        }
    }


}
```

Y un ejemplo de todo esto funcionando sería:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string rutaFichero = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "correo.xml");

        EmailData emData = new ConsoleApplication2.EmailData()
        {
            Body = "mensaje...",
            Host = "el host",
            MailFrom = "yo@e.es",
            MailTo = "Tu@e.es",
            Port = 22,
            SmtpDeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Subject = "subject",
            UseDefaultCredentials = false

        };

        emData.SerializarYGuardar(rutaFichero);

        EmailData result = SerializerExtensions.DesSerialize<EmailData>(rutaFichero);

    }

}
```

Después de hacer  `EmailData result = SerializerExtensions.DesSerialize<EmailData>(rutaFichero);` ya tendrás los datos cargados pudiendo rellenar así tu email con ellos.